# How can the following mathematical statements be proven?

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing

I have these two mathematical statements:
1) $e^{i\pi}=-1$ and
2) $\ln(-1)=i\pi$.
Now I want a proof of these statements. Can anyone help me proving these statements?

Comment: Are you familiar with [Euler's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity)? How have you defined the functions involved, and what have you tried?

Comment: Do you know the definitions of the functions involved?

Comment: You can prove $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ by deriving both sides, then put $x=\pi$

Comment: It depends on how $e^z$ was defined to you.

Comment: The second statement is false. The logarithm is a multi-valued function. We have $\ln z = \ln|z| + \operatorname{i}\arg z$. Since $\{ \pi + 2\pi k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ are all valid arguments for $-1$, we have infinitely many values for $\ln(-1)$. The one you state corresponds to $k=0$.

Comment: But Wolfram Alpha says that ln(-1)=π*i is true.

Comment: @NorbertWillhelm, it's time for you (and us all) to learn the lesson: WA is wrong lots of times in lots of different subjects. It is, of course, a great site where one can **verify** what was already done, but to base one's answer on it...tsk,tsk,tsk. Fly by Night is right, and the reason is a little deep if you haven't yet studied complex analysis.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In the future I will not rely on Wolfram Alpha alone.

Answer (score 2):

That's straightforward
$$e^{i\pi}=\cos(\pi)+i\sin(\pi)=-1$$

Comment: You can put MathJaX code between `$$`.

Comment: @IanMateus thank you :) I didn't realize that... this is my first answer here ... :D

Answer (score 1):

If you take the definition (high school, usually)

$$\text{For}\;\;x\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;e^{ix}:=\cos x+i\sin x\implies e^{\pi i}=\cos\pi+i\sin\pi=-1$$

and now, choosing the branch $\;\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;\text{Im}\,z\ge 0\}\;$ for the logarithm (in this case, it means that $\;\arg(-1)=\pi\;$ ) , we get

$$\text{Log}\,(-1):=\log|-1|+i\arg(-1)=0+\pi i$$